# Is it possible to create a customized nested DataGrid similar to the Visual Studio Work Item query results?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, tfs

I'm currently using a ListView to display a list of items in my Windows Form application. These items are TFS Work Items, and changesets that are related to them.

I would like to emulate a control much more similar to Visual Studio's Work Item query results. From what I can tell, this is a DataGrid that has been customized to allow for nesting, which is my most sought after feature.

[image: For instance, at the bottom of this image.]
<sub>(source: [microsoft.co.il](https://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/eranruso/Tree_of_Work_Items_0F561B6C.png))</sub>

For instance, at the bottom of the image above.

I've searched around, and found custom DataGridViews and DataGrids, but they seem overly complex for a seemingly simple operation. A DataGrid with relations seems like it's the right direction, but I'm hoping to mirror how users expand nested Work Items; using the small right-angle-arrow next to the Title, as opposed to the first column including the plus/minus error.

My hope is that this should be very similar to users of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

On TFS side, you can get linked query programmatically, there is a demo solution at website: http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2011/07/10/tfs-2010-sdk-get-projects-iterations-area-path-queries-and.aspx

```
                   if (query.IsLinkQuery)

                    {
                        var queryResults = query.RunLinkQuery();

                        lblQuery.Text = String.Format("Query Text Below | Query Type: {0}", "Linked Query");
                        label6.Text = String.Format("Total {0}", queryResults.Length);
                        foreach (WorkItemLinkInfo item in queryResults)
                        {
                            lstWorkItems.Items.Add(detailsOfTheSelectedProject.Store.GetWorkItem(item.TargetId).Id);
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: This question isn't so much about getting the linked queries programtically, but getting a control that will allow me to display the results in a fashion more familiar to users of Visual Studio.